# Get Average from String 00:00:00 with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some data to analyse. One example is a list of durations of tasks:

```
$tasks.duration

00:04:44
00:00:00
00:00:05
```

Is there a simple way to get the avarage duration from this list? Obviously you can't just use something like Measure-Object, because it's a string with special characters.

How would you approach this and why?

Comment: Are you sure those are not `TimeSpan` values? Even if they are strings, you should be able to parse `TimeSpan`s from them and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obviously you can't just use something like Measure-Object, because it's a string with special characters.

Parse the strings into [`[timespan]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) values, then calculate the average number of seconds in each, turn the result back into a `[timespan]` and then finally produce a correctly formatted string:

```
$measurement = $tasks.duration |ForEach-Object {
  # cast string value to [timespan], output TotalSeconds
  ([timespan]$_).TotalSeconds
} |Measure-Object -Average

# Now we can create a new string value based on the average number of seconds
$avgString = [timespan]::FromSeconds($measurement.Average).ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
```

Which, with the sample values you've provided, gives:

```
PS ~> $avgString
00:01:36
```

Comment: Nicely done; just to offer a concise alternative using an array cast combined with the newly (re)baptized [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature: `([timespan[]] ('00:04:44', '00:00:05')).TotalSeconds | Measure-Object -Average`

Comment: @mklement0 That'd work as well, but I deliberately cast them 1 by 1 - easier to spot invalid input values based on error message with the individual conversions than with array conversion :)

Comment: Makes sense; that's a good hint for deciding which approach is more appropriate in a given situation. _If_ you can assume all strings are well-formed, the array-cast + member-access enumeration has the added advantage of being faster (though with small arrays that won't matter).